# Using Variables to name Variables in Applescript

Tags: applescript

So I want to have different Variables with the same name, except for the numbers at the end. The number increases over time, since it's in a repeat loop.

```
set i to 0
repeat 6 times
      set i to i + 1
      set SampleVar & i to i + 10
end repeat
end run
```

This Syntax is probably completely wrong but, I hope you understand, what I want to achieve.

Comment: You cannot dynamically create variables like that, they need to be declared at compile time.  The normal way to use collections would be to use a `list` or `record`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments by red_menace:

> You cannot dynamically create variables like that, they need to be declared at compile time. The normal way to use collections would be to use a `list` or `record`.

This is your script rewritten to use lists:

```
set SampleList to {}
set i to 0
repeat 6 times
    set i to i + 1
    set the end of SampleList to i
end repeat
```

I don't know what the advantages of writing it as a record are but it usually takes longer and I'm not quite as familiar with them as I am with lists.